# Docker: Why is docker compose not starting other containers?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services: 
  mongodb:
    image: mongo 
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment: # environmental variables
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

When i run the `up` command

```bash
docker compose up
```

The `mongodb` is running but the `mongo-express` is not running, in the logs i see a message that says:

```bash
app-mongo-express-1 exited with code 0
```

When i run the `ps` command i see only one container running:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                      NAMES
562b810882b6   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   app-mongodb-1
```

Why is mongo-express not running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you have added dependency between mongodb and mongo-express. You need to add     **depends_on** under mongo-express.  Of course since mongo-express cannot connect to the mongodb it fails and added restart: always to mongo-express

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
  mongodb:
    image: mongo 
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment: # environmental variables
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, after I added that it did not work again.

Comment: Fixed the  error by adding restart: always to mongo-express. Updated the answer accordingly as well

Comment: yes it's working now thank's so much.